# giving a field two valid types in Mongoose schema type options

Tags: mongoose-schema

I want to have a field within a document that is only allowed to be an object or an array of objects:

```
const { Schmea } = require('mongoose')
const someSchema = new Schema({
  friend: (Object || [Object]) // something like that
})
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible, what you need in that case is to use `Schema.Types.Mixed`.

[Here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed) you have the docs.

Following your example, it should look like this:

```js
const someSchema = new Schema({
  friend: Schema.Types.Mixed
})
```